# Flex to Flex simple TCP connection

Tags: apache-flex, tcp, air

I'm working on a large file transfer(P2P) in UDP air application. I want to connect client and server using TCP. Can anybody tell me how to connect both both in TCP. Thank you.

Comment: You said "UDP air application" and then "using TCP".  Which is it, UDP or TCP?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for responding. I'm first connecting client with server using TCP and after server response I want to start file transfer using UDP. Yes, this is in air application.

Now I got some use full stuff on below links.
http://www.codeweblog.com/actionscript-3-0-socket-programming/

I used Socket at client side and ServerSocket at server side for TCP connection for connection establishment. Later I started file transfer.